# Complex Queries in Crate DB possible?

Tags: mysql, sql, crate

i just want to convert my all MYSQL tables into crate tables. This is actually an mobile app backend. Is it really possible in Crate to do exact query operation similar to MYSQL.

I didn't see any JOIN, Intersect, union ..etc. Even i can't use subquery (IN operator) in crate.

I also didn't see primary key ==> foreignKey relations set on table.

Please help me to do all the above on Crate DB.

"I love crate". it seems really faster,  but it lacks on Complex Query to excute as like normal MYSQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crate currently doesn't support joins or subselects. Although support will be added in the future (see https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7611399)

There are also no relations between tables which is why there are no foreign key.

Many of the things that are accomplished using joins can instead be done by de-normalizing the model and make use of the object and array types.

Update: With 0.54.X there is initial (limited) support for joins.
Limited in that some forms (outer joins for example) are missing and that there is still a lot of room for performance improvements.

Comment: This is actually i predicted. I am done the feasibility study on Crate DB. Going to submit report. thanks.

Comment: Having come from MySQL myself, I must say moving away from joins was a mind-bender but also refreshingly liberating once I got into the swing of using object and array types.